# Certificate Creation Error Digital Ocean Lets Encrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I want to deploy a rails app to my server on Digital Ocean, but before I do that I want to add SSL. I've followed the tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) but get the following error in Step 2:

```
Failed authorization procedure. www.xxx.co.za (http-01):urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www.xxx.co.za, xxx.co.za (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://xxx.co.za/.well-known/acme-challenge/d1kKPdePX3MLO6kMt1pAdFets-N0RkQ_ffM3Y5aEBO8 [xxx.xx.xxx.xx]: 404

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: xxx.co.za
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from http://xxx.co.za/.well-known
   /acme-challenge/d1kKPdePX3MLO6kMt1pAdFets-N0RkQ_ffM3Y5aEBO8
   [xxx.xx.xxx.xx]: 404

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.xxx.co.za
   Type:   connection
   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www.xxx.co.za
```

For privacy reasons Ive marked out the IP and Domain name. I also ran a dig request, but not sure what this means.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.7-Ubuntu <<>> xxx.co.za
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18315
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xxx.co.za.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
xxx.co.za.      1799    IN  A   xxx.xx.xxx.xx

;; Query time: 194 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue May 10 10:55:38 SAST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59
```

Any suggestions? I did only edit the DNS settings on my domain host about 12 hours ago, is this the problem, should I wait longer? What does the "AUTHORITY: 0" mean? Is this part of the problem? I've only worked with Heroku before and they do everything for you, now that I manage the server, its a bit more complex. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found that one should point to the rails app's nginx configuration file in

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/rails
```

and then make note of the root directory for your app and use that when generating the certificate. Also remember to reboot your server after configuration changes and try to use the web based console from Digital Ocean as far as possible.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: I do not understand your soution. Can you post more detail?

Comment: I used the One Click App setup in Digital Ocean's droplets. This seems to have different Nginx settings than setting up a droplet from scratch. So, the configuration file which one needs to edit when using the tutorial as per the link supplied in my question, has to be the one supplied in my answer. Also, it appears that rails doesn't have subdomains, so one cant use example.com when requesting a certificate from Lets Encrypt, only www.example.com. Or at least, this is what I know. @inye